# How to detect device in template file in drupal 7

Tags: theming

I want to get the device whether is it Mobile,Tablet,Iphone or desktop based on the screen width. I know about breakpoint and picture module. But I need to change some HTML based on that condition. How can I get the condition in tpl file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [Context](https://www.drupal.org/project/context) & [Context Mobile Detect](https://www.drupal.org/project/context_mobile_detect)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please explain it how to setup this so that I can access its variable in template files.